# Control font size and color in TinyMCERTE editor (version:4.1.6)

Tags: tinymce, modx

I am using MODX CMS and it consists TinyMCERTE editor (version:4.1.6) in which font size and color control is not available. I tried to find out the solution which shows that plugin is available for newer version only.

here is the screenshot of Tiny Editor and the source folder:

[Tiny Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtlkG.jpg)

[Tiny JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYmPD.jpg)

Comment: What version of Modx are you running? (Also, you could try CK Editor as well https://modx.com/extras/package/ckeditor)

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, currently i am using this modx version (MODX Revolution 2.2.15-pl (traditional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go in system settings and add to this two rows this values -

in `tinymcerte.toolbar1` add to the end after white space: `fontsizeselect forecolor`

in `tinymcerte.plugins` add to the end after white space: `textcolor`

[image]

after that - two new buttons will appear:

[image]

Comment: One more thing is there any tutorial for upgrading this (TIny) plugin.

Comment: How upgrading? If you want to chage some colors in `textcolor` plugin - you need to include your external config ( see `tinymcerte.external_config` system setting)